# Jenkins git fetch intermittent failure

Tags: git, jenkins

It seems that some overnight Jenkins jobs are failing intermittently, so they only fail sometimes. Console output below:

```
Started by timer
Checking out git ssh://git@gitlab.domain.com:2222/repo-here.git into /opt/jenkins/home/workspace/job_name@script to read Jenkinsfile
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository ssh://git@gitlab.domain.com:2222/repo-here.git
 > git init /opt/jenkins/home/workspace/job-name@script # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@gitlab.domain.com:2222/repo-here.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials GitLab SSH Key for  jenkins
 > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@gitlab.domain.com:2222/repo-here.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@gitlab.domain.com:2222/repo-here.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2002)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1721)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:405)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:614)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:298)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkins version: Jenkins ver. 2.126
Git: 3.9.0
Git client plugin: 2.7.2
OS: CentOS

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 running Jenkins in Docker. I'm not sure that there is a solution to this.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution on another thread that solved the exact same issue for me:
https://serverfault.com/questions/924058/jenkins-occasionally-fails-to-clone-fetch

If you have several Jenkins jobs that fetch the git repository simultaneously via ssh, then you should increase the value of `MaxStartups` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the git server side.

The default value is 10:30:100 (which means that 30% of new connections will be dropped when 10 are already opened), I set the value 30:30:100 and then I have no more issue.

Comment: /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the git server right? if so,  adjusting git server central settings is not always an option for all people and also it might have impact in other projects not suing jenkins... and this solution is not so scalable, lets say in future you want to run in parallel jobs in > 100 nodes....

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 possible resons to get this kind of issue.

1. As per the logs, we are getting status code as 128. So cross check the user have access to the repo and branch, which you are cloning.
2. Make sure you are using correct repo name and branch name. other wise similar kind of will occur.

Comment: It's an intermittent issue so the details must be correct.

Comment: Could you answer following questions. are you using GitHub or VSTS-GIT? if it is VSTS-GIT, then are you using alternative credentials or not?

Comment: Git plugin and using gitlab as the repo.